How to form feminine counterparts of nouns ending in -or /-nte?
I saw a phrase  "La gobernador". What does it mean? Is it a gubernator who happens to be a female? (my intuition would be La gobernadora), why  is it   not?  Apparently, in the context where I saw it, it  referred  to the gubernator , irrespectively of  their gender. Then what specifically does it mean? And more generally, do nouns ending in -ora have  usage  peculiarities? Is it always an -or who happens to be a female? For example, in Mexico, a female Doctor is referred as Doctora, both as a person  holding the academic degree and a medical Doctor (but not referring to the degree itself: not * María recibió el  grado de Doctora, where one would say Juan recibió el grado de Doctor). On the other hand,  in Mexico there is an important historical figure  La Corregidora, who did not have the title  of Corregidor herself, but was wife of the Corregidor. however,  La Doctora is typically a Doctor (PhD or medical Doctor) herself, not wife  of a Doctor. Is there  a rule or regularity in the  forms in -ora   to refer to  female -or or wife of -or?
As for the nouns in -nte, educated people in Mexico angrily reject forms such as * Presidenta *(mostly used by feminists)  or * estudianta. Is there any  linguistically correct  form to express this meaning? Probably the answer is just La Presidente? Is it?

gubernator is not a word, the word in English is: governor.

The general rule states that nouns ending in -or form the feminine by adding "a", while those ending in "ante" or "ente" remain the same:

pastor / pastora
lector / lectora
doctor / doctora
gobernador / gobernadora

There are exceptions like: actor / actriz - emperador / emperatriz

viajante / viajante
paciente / paciente
estudiante / estudiante
regente / regente

With "presidente", it is true that feminists will claim that "presidenta" is the correct form, but even RAE considers it is the one to be used. However, some speakers will stick to the general rule and say "la presidente".

Reglas generales:
Masculinos:
Generalmente terminan en -o, como:
El niño
El perro
El libro
También son masculinos los sustantivos terminados en -aje, -or, -án, -e (en algunos casos), y -ma:
El viaje
El doctor
El pan
El problema
Femeninos:
Generalmente terminan en -a, como:
La niña
La perra
La casa
También son femeninos los sustantivos terminados en -ción, -sión, -dad, -tad, -umbre:
La acción
La canción
La ciudad
La amistad
La costumbre
Ejemplos de sustantivos masculinos:
El hombre
El gato
El árbol
El zapato
El día
Ejemplos de sustantivos femeninos:
La mujer
La gata
La flor
La silla
La noche
Excepciones:
Algunos sustantivos no siguen las reglas anteriores, y hay que aprenderlos de memoria. Por ejemplo:
El agua (femenino, aunque empieza con "a", se usa el artículo "el" debido a que "agua" es un sustantivo que empieza con una "a" tónica).
El día (masculino, aunque termina en -a).
Sustantivos comunes en cuanto al género:
Algunos sustantivos pueden ser tanto masculinos como femeninos, dependiendo del contexto, por ejemplo:
El/la cantante
El/la estudiante
El/la artista.

Hola Nano y bienvenido al sitio. Su respuesta no responde a la pregunta original, porque no habla de las palabras que terminan en "or" ni "nte", entonces no cabe bien aquí.

En cuanto a "la gobernador".
El uso normal es, obviamente, «la gobernadora».
Hoy en día, sin embargo, hay una tendencia a utilizar términos neutros para designar profesiones, independientemente del sexo de la persona que desempeña el trabajo.
Esto ayuda a romper estereotipos y promover la igualdad.
Así, muchas profesionales prefieren títulos que no destaquen su sexo, sino sus cualificaciones y competencias.
Esto es consecuencia de un movimiento más amplio hacia la igualdad de género y el feminismo.
En las lenguas que no tienen artículos femeninos, ésta es ya una tendencia que está ganando popularidad.
Desde este punto de vista, el uso de «la gobernador» podría sustituir completamente a «la gobernadora» en el futuro, cuando esta última se considere obsoleta.
